# Views callback work only once with advanced form block

Tags: 7, views, forms

this code work but the views is callback only once (reload only once), any idea to reload more than one time ?

[see in detail on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/afb/issues/2111755)

```
function modulename_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    switch ($form_id) {
        case 'form_id_of_your_afb_form':
            $form['#validate'] = array();
            $form['ajax-submit']['#ajax']['callback'] = 'modulename_create_callback';
    }
} 
function modulename_create_callback($form, &$form_state) {
    // load view
    $view1 = views_embed_view('view_name','view_display_name',$view_arguments_as_required);

    // replace the afb form with a clean form
    $newform = afb_ajax_handler($form, $form_state);
    $commands = array(
      ajax_command_replace('#target_div_id_of_view_to_update .view',$view1),
      ajax_command_replace('#target_div_id_of_afb_form_to_replace',render($newform)),
    );
    $form['#type'] = 'ajax';
    $form['#commands'] = $commands;
    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description and code you have only one requirement that is **update views block on form submission**. So,

- You don't have to alter the form AJAX as [AFB](https://www.drupal.org/project/afb) form submission already uses AJAX.
- Furthermore, you don't have to replace the form using [ajax_command_replace()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/function/ajax_command_replace/7.x) as its already replacing using [AFB](https://www.drupal.org/project/afb)
- You don't have even to return the form as well.

**What do you need is to**

- Get the Term ID and set as views contextual filter
- Alter AJAX rendering using [HOOK_ajax_render_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_ajax_render_alter/7.x)
- Replace using [ajax_command_replace()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/function/ajax_command_replace/7.x)

**So, use below code to get it worked.**

```
function MODULENAME_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    switch ($form_id) {
        case 'sport_node_form':
            if ($term = menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2)) $_SESSION['tid'] = $term->tid;
    }
}
function MODULENAME_ajax_render_alter(&$commands) {
    if(isset($_SESSION['tid']) && is_numeric($_SESSION['tid'])){
        $mavue_new = render(views_embed_view('mavue_new','default', $_SESSION['tid']));
        $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('.view-mavue-new', $mavue_new);
    }
}
```

I hope this would help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to put the number of tid directly here :

```
ajax_command_replace('#target_div_id_of_view_to_update .view','1'),
```